# Binding multiple implementations, depending on the host class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I have two interfaces: `UserService` and `ProjectService`. Each of them has a specific implementation class, named `UserServiceImpl` and `ProjectServiceImpl`, respectively. There is also a `WorkflowManagementService` class, which implements the two aforementioned interfaces, and works as a proxy for their concrete implementations. It also does more stuff on top.

The `WorkflowManagementService` gets injected with concrete `UserService` and `ProjectService` instances. For the rest of the application though, whenever someone needs a `UserSerivce` or a `ProjectService` instance, a `WorkflowManagementService` should be provided.

How can I make so that the injector provides `UserServiceImpl` and ProjectServiceImpl, if they are to be injected in `WorkflowManagementService`, and `WorkflowManagementService` for any other reference?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this based on class context but you could do this with a binding annotation:

```java
public class Example {

  static interface UserService {}
  static interface ProjectService {}

  static class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {}
  static class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {}

  static class WorkflowManagementService implements UserService, ProjectService {
    @Inject
    @Named("concrete")
    UserService userService;

    @Inject
    @Named("concrete")
    ProjectService projectService;
  }

  static class Module extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(UserService.class).to(WorkflowManagementService.class);
      bind(ProjectService.class).to(WorkflowManagementService.class);
      bind(UserService.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("concrete")).to(UserServiceImpl.class);
      bind(ProjectService.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("concrete")).to(ProjectServiceImpl.class);
    }
  }
}
```

You might want to use an actual annotation instead of `@Named` after you finish prototyping your code.

Comment: If you wanted to encapsulate your bindings even more, you could use a [PrivateModule](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html), and only expose the WorkflowManagementService. This would prevent other consumers from accessing or even seeing the annotated keys. You would probably still need some sort of annotation, as PrivateModules can't override bindings made in their parent injectors. (Nit: I'd favor "unmanaged" over "concrete", as UserService is still an interface. :) )